# Wordpress + BlockUI or a splash page

Tags: jquery, plugin-recommendation, jquery-ui

First - I don't want to invite a wheel which may exists. Second - I'm not sure which method will be most effective in my case.

I have a website where there are a lot of galleries with high-res photos and kind of large thumbnails (about 350x235 on average) which makes those pages to load slowly. On those pages I want to do some kind of quote and under that quote a message about that page may load slowly.

I have tried to use jQuery BlockUI executing based on page ID. I have added my code to the wp-header.php but I wasn't able to get it activated when the page started to load (as first), then load all images "in the background" and deactivate when all got loaded on the page.

As a generic solution for my issue I thought that maybe there are some kind of plugins which create a splash page before loading "main" page but what I saw can load that kind of splash page before the home page or all other pages but not selected one.

Any thoughts or suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Images that are 350x235 shouldn't load slowly. I would recommend trying to speed up your site before looking into adding custom code or a loading screen. A plugin like [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) will optimize your images in a lossless compression (no degradation of image quality) and a cache plugin will help with compressing pages to get them to load faster. [Here](https://www.designbombs.com/top-wordpress-caching-plugins-compared/) is a good review of the best caching plugins, you can choose based on your budget, several are free.

Comment: I have already WP Super Cache and added site to Cloudflare to get those images distributed around the world to reduce main site download. I will check that image optimizer if it will helps. Also not sure if hosting (BlueHost) is not the source of that slowness as well.

Comment: Any suggestion for an image optimizer for existing (already uploaded) images?

Comment: Have you run your site through a speed test to see if it is loading slowly, and if so, what may be causing it? Have you experimented with your cache settings? Are you getting to the limits of shared hosting?

Comment: @KennethOdle I have run the site through the GTmetrix and only suggestions which I have got are to optimize images, which has a sense, and leverage browser caching for the cacheable resources, IMO in that case WP Super Cache should do that. PS. I see that browser caching can be done via .htaccess and most common issue for WP Super Cache (compared to the Total Cache). What will be good time expiration on images which are not changed but only deleted (once per year)

Comment: It depends on how often you delete them, I suppose. There are some image optimizing plugins available, see https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/image+optimizer/ (I have not tried any of those, however.)